# Reloading in private route taking user to login page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-router-dom, redux-toolkit

I am trying to implement a private route in react app. I am using Redux and Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query for state management and data fetching. Now when I reload in the private page, it navigates me to login page and it does not goes into the `if (isLoading) { return <p>Loading.............</p>; }`condition.

When I reload the page, the user info is updated in the redux store but I also get navigated to login page. How can I fix this?

Here is the `RequireAuth` component

```js
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import { useAppSelector } from "../../redux/hooks";
import { Navigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const RequireAuth = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { user, isLoading } = useAppSelector((state) => state?.auth);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading.............</p>;
  }
  if (!user?.email && !isLoading) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }}></Navigate>;
  }
  return children;
};

export default RequireAuth;
```

Here is the initial state:

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  user: {
    email: "",
    accountStatus: "",
    role: "",
    id: "",
  },
  isLoading: false,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    userLoggedIn: (state, action) => {
      const { accessToken, ...userInfo } = action.payload;
      state.user = userInfo;
    },
    userLoggedOut: (state) => {
      state.user = {
        email: "",
        accountStatus: "",
        role: "",
        id: "",
      };
    },
    toggleLoading: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = !state.isLoading;
    },
  },
});

export const { userLoggedIn, userLoggedOut, toggleLoading } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

and here is the RTK-Query endpoint:

```js
const authApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    persistLogin: builder.query({
      query: (payload) => ({
        url: "/auth/persist-login",
        method: "GET",
        body: payload,
      }),
      async onQueryStarted(_data, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
          dispatch(toggleLoading());
          const result = await queryFulfilled;
          dispatch(userLoggedIn(result.data.data));
          dispatch(toggleLoading());
        } catch (error) {
          // nothing to do here
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

I am calling the `usePersistLoginQuery` hook in app.tsx to persist user each time user reloads the page.

Answer (score 2):

The `isLoading` state value is initially false, so the app, and the route you are protecting, starts out from a non-loading condition.

Start from an assumed loading condition. You should probably also be more explicit about what the loading state is being set to instead of just toggling.

```js
const initialState = {
  user: {
    email: "",
    accountStatus: "",
    role: "",
    id: "",
  },
  isLoading: true, // <-- initially loading
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    userLoggedIn: (state, action) => {
      const { accessToken, ...userInfo } = action.payload;
      state.user = userInfo;
    },
    userLoggedOut: (state) => {
      state.user = {
        email: "",
        accountStatus: "",
        role: "",
        id: "",
      };
    },
    toggleLoading: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
```

```js
const authApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    persistLogin: builder.query({
      query: (payload) => ({
        url: "/auth/persist-login",
        method: "GET",
        body: payload,
      }),
      async onQueryStarted(_data, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
          dispatch(toggleLoading(true));  // <-- start loading
          const result = await queryFulfilled;
          dispatch(userLoggedIn(result.data.data));
        } catch (error) {
          // nothing to do here
        } finally {
          dispatch(toggleLoading(false)); // <-- clear loading
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```